# Xubuntu 18.04 HWE kernel 5.4.0-42 breaks wireless on Asus laptop

Tags: networking, 18.04, kernel

Running Xubuntu 18.04 on an Asus (AMD), and originally had to install hwe to get wireless working.  I just updated from kernel 5.3.0-62-generic to 5.4.0-42-generic and now the wireless does not work.  Was able to boot into that older version and wireless worked as usual.

Removed 5.4.0-42-generic and everything is working again, but would like to stay on the latest kernel.  Let me know if additional information can help.

Comment: You can put a *hold* (`apt-mark`) on the kernel that works, so it won't be removed; which is a great short term solution, but I'd suggest filing (or searching for a bug of that *regression*) as staying on an older kernel introduces security risk into your system.